# Error: List object in a class with import java.util.List;

Tags: java, json, list

I am trying to write a project that imports a weather API json to java and I am getting a conflict error. In the below you can see part of the json that I need the java object to be generated for it and it needs to be a list object class. First of all I am really confused about how to write an object class as a list(I searched for this problem but no answer or tutorial was precise enough for me) and second of all the name of the class that should be "list" to match the json (as I understand) produces a conflict with the import java.util.List;

```
"list": [

{
    "dt": 1399950000,
    "main": {
        "temp": 287.82,
        "temp_min": 287.82,
        "temp_max": 287.82,
        "pressure": 923.74,
        "sea_level": 1018.93,
        "grnd_level": 923.74,
        "humidity": 100,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 501,
            "main": "Rain",
            "description": "moderate rain",
            "icon": "10d"
        }
    ],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 92
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 0.51,
        "deg": 226.005
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 6
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2014-05-13 03:00:00"
},
{
    "dt": 1399960800,
    "main": {
        "temp": 291.36,
        "temp_min": 291.358,
        "temp_max": 291.36,
        "pressure": 921.65,
        "sea_level": 1016.09,
        "grnd_level": 921.65,
        "humidity": 87,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 500,
            "main": "Rain",
            "description": "light rain",
            "icon": "10d"
        }
    ],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 20
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 0.87,
        "deg": 12.0018
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0.5
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
    },
```

As you can see inside the json I have a list object that I need to map it into java object. The java class with list object is as below:

```
package weather.data;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class List{

    List list = new ArrayList();
    private Main main;
    private Clouds clouds;
    private Number dt;
    private Weather weather;
    private Wind wind;
    private Rain rain;
    private Sys sys;
    private String dt_txt;

    public Main getMain(){
        return this.main;
    }
    public void setMain(Main main){
        this.main = main;
    }

    ...
       //The rest of setters and getters
}
```

I get this error in front of the import java.util.List: The import java.util.List conflicts with a type defined in the same file
and this error in front of List list = new ArrayList();
Multiple markers at this line
    - ArrayList is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayList should be 
     parameterized
    - Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList to List
    - ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type

I also tried to change the name of the object to list1 but when I tried to run the code I faced another error: Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of weather.data.list1 out of START_ARRAY token at [Source: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/4b32c7ef1ceb5dd48bf5/raw/ef1987551faa3fb61473bb0e7aad70a228dc36d6/gistfile1.txt; line: 15, column: 14] (through reference chain: weather.data.Jweather["list"]) at ...

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please include a working subset of the json in the question itself - links often break over time.

Comment: 'list' property in the json does not mean your class name should be List. As you see there is already a class in java jdk with name List. Change the class name. something like `public class MyList`

Comment: You'll need to refer to the java List as java.util.List everywhere you use it so that it does not need to be imported (as it clashes with your class name). Better yet, don't call your class List (unless you have no choice).

Comment: `import java.util.List;

public class List{

    List list = new ArrayList();` nothing jumps at you?

Comment: @njzk2 can you be clearer? If you have any suggestion please tell me. I hate to mention I am new in java all the time in my questions, but it seems I have to do that.

Comment: the error is very explicit: `The import java.util.List conflicts with a type defined in the same file`

Comment: @njzk2 Yes I know that and I mentioned it in my question. I also mentioned when I changed the name of the class (for instance to list1) what error I received. Anyway I have already changed the name and it seems the error is due to the way I have written my beans. I changed many things in them but it still gives me a similar error to the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to implement your own linked list class.  Better just to use the `LinkedList` class that comes in the JDK, if that is the functionality that you want, and have a `Readings` class (or `Weather`, or whatever name would be meaningful to you) that stores all the numbers, and the temperature and so on, but not the "next" node of the list.

Answer (score 2):

Your class named `List` is shadowing `java.util.List`, so your field is of the type of this class; that's what the compiler is telling you. Avoid naming your classes the same simple names as core API classes, and use generic parameters on collections.

Comment: Thanks I have applied what you are saying and it worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your class name and run it will work fine,as your class-name and List name are same you are getting that error.

Answer (score -1):

Name of your class is `List` while jre has its own class List in `java.util.List` which you are importing.

Change the name of your class, it cant be any java's API name